# linker command failed with exit code 1 clang:error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

```
Ld /Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/HelvetiQuiz.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelvetiQuiz normal armv7
    cd /Users/simona/Desktop/Ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath -F/Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath -filelist /Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/HelvetiQuiz.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelvetiQuiz.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -liPhone-lib -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/HelvetiQuiz.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelvetiQuiz_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/simona/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelvetiQuiz-euzcyknolfniushksjdmyofanxpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/HelvetiQuiz.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelvetiQuiz

ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get this error whenn I try to compile my app. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

These articles may be of use:

- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/538363/error-when-i-updated-to-xcode-5-to-get-import-to-i.html
- http://xyglo.com/blog/2013/11/06/xcode-linker-mystery/

Some quick googling turns up a lot of cases where unity users have had this issue and it is related to the Library Search Path settings (Project -> target -> build settings).